# Как отправлять целые числа с клиента на сервер.Python socket

Tags: python, сокет, клиент-сервер, преобразование-типов

Кто шарит в клиент-сервере на python,библиотека socket помогите решить задачу пожалуйста.

СЕРВЕР ЗАДАЧА:

1. Создайте сервер, который получает число, умножает его на 10 и отправляет обратно клиенту.
2. При получении команды «stop», сервер должен быть остановлен (в примере из урока это можно сделать, завершив бесконечный цикл с помощью break).

КЛИЕНТ ЗАДАЧА:

1. Создайте клиента, который отправляет серверу из предыдущего упражнения число 5, затем ещё число 10 и затем команду «stop».
2. Убедитесь, что всё работает правильно, то есть сервер после первой команды должен прислать «50», после второй – «100», а после команды «stop» должен быть остановлен (то есть программа из предыдущего упражнения должна остановиться).

КОД СЕРВЕРА

```
import socket

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('', 15253)

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
server.listen(1)
print("Ждём подключения клиента...")
while True:
    c, a = server.accept()
    data = c.recv(4096)
    b = data.decode("UTF-8")
    print("Получили от клиента:", b)
    if b == 'stop':
        print("Заверешение")
        break
    data = data * 10
    c.send(data)
    c.close()
```

КОД КЛИЕНТА

```
import socket

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 15253)

client = socket.socket()
client.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS)
client.send(bytes("5", encoding="UTF-8"))
data = client.recv(4096)
print(data.decode("UTF-8"))
```

Проблема в том что я не знаю как конвертировать строку в число именно в этой теме т.к. там чтение идёт в байтах.
При запуске клиент-сервера возвращается 10 пятёрок
С командой "stop" всё получилось .

Comment: int(data,2) не работает ? если там бин строка

Answer (score 1):

Ваш  сервер проще исправить так:

```
    break
data=bytes(str(int(data) *10), "ascii" )
c.send(data)
```

Но я бы рекомендовал использовать какой-то протокол для передачи для более сложных задачек. Например, реализовать TLV:

сервер

```
INT=1
STOPSERVER=2
END=3

accepting = True

while accepting:
    c, a = server.accept()
    while True:
        data = c.recv(2)
        type, length = data
        if length:
            data = c.recv(length)
        
        if type == END:
            break

        if type == STOPSERVER:
            accepting = False
            break

        if type == INT:
            data = int.from_bytes(data,"big")
            data *= 10
            c.send(bytes[INT,4])
            c.send(data.to_bytes(4,'big'))
    c.close()
```

клиент

```
client.send(bytes[INT,4])
client.send((5).to_bytes(4,'big'))
client.send(bytes[END,0])
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,всё получилось!